# Writing BMP files (Platform Independent)

Tags: bmp

I have a structure such as

```
   typedef struct  FT_Bitmap_
  {
    int             rows;
    int             width;
    int             pitch;
    unsigned char*  buffer;
    short           num_grays;
    char            pixel_mode;
    char            palette_mode;
    void*           palette;

  } FT_Bitmap;
```

defining my bitmap data

I want to create a valid bmp file from this structure. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Write out the header, the palette and the data.

Just take care when you write the bitmap data. It's "upside-down" - the first pixel in data is the left-bottom corner pixel.

Comment: thank you. The thing is, I dont know which elements in my struct would go to which elements in the bmp file.

Comment: First you print out the generic BMP header. After that, you write the DIB header - this is where you print out height, width and the other information you have on your struct. After that, you pallete (also in your header). And, at last, go through you buffer (in your header again), writing pixel per pixel in the output file.

You might want to take a look at this example:

http://www.kalytta.com/bitmap.h

Answer (score 1):

First declare three types of initializers you will mostly use:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned short word;
typedef unsigned long dword;
```

As for the structs, i suggest you using three, each for the element of the BMP:

```
typedef struct BITMAPINFOHEADER
{
    dword bmp_size;
    word bmp_app1;
    word bmp_app2;
    dword bmp_offset;
} BMP;

typedef struct DIB_HEADER
{
    dword dib_size;
    dword dib_w;
    dword dib_h;
    word dib_planes;
    word dib_bits;
    dword dib_compression;
    dword dib_rawsize;
    dword dib_xres;
    dword dib_yres;
    dword dib_palette;
    dword dib_important;
} DIB;

typedef struct PIXEL_ARRAY
{
    byte B;
    byte G;
    byte R;
} PIX;
```

Then you can manipulate the image in many ways. You can make an 1D/2D array to contain the data or just manipulate the bmp directly. The following code makes 500x460 colored blank bmp directly:

```
void new (char NAME[] , byte RED , byte GREEN , byte BLUE)
{
    char build_name[256];
    const char* id = "BM";
    int i, j;
    char debug[128];

    FILE* fp;

    dword rsize = (500 * sizeof(PIX) + 3) / 4 * 4;
    dword pad = rsize - 500 * sizeof(PIX);
    dword rawsize = rsize * 460 * sizeof(PIX);
    byte zero[3] = {0};

    dword size      = (2) + sizeof(BMP) + sizeof(DIB) + sizeof(PIX);

    BMP bmp[] = { 2+sizeof(BMP)+sizeof(DIB)+(sizeof(rawsize)/4), 0, 0, 2+sizeof(BMP)+sizeof(DIB) }; //2+ [!]
    DIB dib[] = { sizeof(DIB), 500, 460, 1, 24, 0, (sizeof(rawsize)/4), 2835, 2835, 0, 0 };
    PIX pix;
    pix.R = RED;
    pix.G = GREEN;
    pix.B = BLUE;

    sprintf(build_name, "%s.bmp", NAME);
    fp = fopen(build_name, "wb");
    if(!fp) strcpy(debug, "Access Denied.");
    else strcpy(debug, "Saved.");

    fwrite(id, 1, 2, fp);
    fwrite(&bmp, 1, sizeof(bmp), fp);
    fwrite(&dib, 1, sizeof(dib), fp);

    for(i = 0; i < 460; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 500; j++)
        {
            fwrite(&pix, sizeof(pix), 1, fp);
        }
        if (pad) fwrite(zero, 1, pad, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

The point is using `fseek()` to locate the pixel and `fwrite()` to write pixels directly.